# Google Cloud Storage Bucket CORS error although CORS policy set

Tags: google-cloud-storage, signed-url

I have a signedURL for a google cloud storage bucket, and I want to use it with axios to make a PUT request.

My putFileData function is called when the variable signedURL is not empty, via useEffect.

```
  const putFileData = async () => {
    await axios
    .put(signedURL, "HELLO TXT!!!!")
    .then((response) => console.log(response))
    .catch(err => {console.log("AXIOS ERROR: ", err)})  
}
```

I set the CORS policy on the bucket with a json file, and when I query the bucket's cors policy I get:

```
[{"maxAgeSeconds": 360, "method": ["PUT"], "origin": ["http://localhost:3000"], "responseHeader": ["Content-Type"]}]
```

The options on my signedURL are:

```
const options = {
  version: 'v4',
  action: 'write',
  expires: Date.now() + 15 * 60 * 1000, // 15 minutes
  contentType: 'application/octet-stream',
};
```

Yet I still can't do the PUT request from http://localhost:3000.

I get:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'mysignedurl' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

and:

```
PUT mysignedurl::ERR_FAILED
```

In my Network tab of Chrome Developer tools it shows the request is made twice - first unsuccessfully with status 403, then successfully with status 200 - yet nothing is uploaded to the bucket.

My signed url is generated with this function in my Cloud Functions:

```
async function generateV4UploadSignedUrl(bucketName, fileName) {
// These options will allow temporary uploading of the file with outgoing
// Content-Type: application/octet-stream header.
const options = {
  version: 'v4',
  action: 'write',
  expires: Date.now() + 15 * 60 * 1000, // 15 minutes
  contentType: 'application/octet-stream',
};

// Get a v4 signed URL for uploading file
const [url] = await storage
  .bucket(bucketName)
  .file(fileName)
  .getSignedUrl(options)
  
return url;
```

};

Comment: Could you please share how are you creating your signed URL ? 
Could you please add the response header as following : "responseHeader": ["Content-Type", "access-control-allow-origin"]}] and check if you still get the error?

Comment: I did amend the responseHeader and I've added the function that generates my signedUrl.

Comment: The signedUrl I get back is one that starts https://storage.googleapis.com/mybucket and that is the JSON Api upload and it seems that doesn't accept CORS, https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/request-endpoints#xml-api but that is the url the signedURL function returns? Is there a way to generate an XML signedURL?

Comment: I have exactly the same code but still getting this error no matter what I try :-/

Comment: Check the IAM Permissions - I found it just gives CORS errors as a sort of general error - it's not that helpful for diagnosing the actual issue.

Comment: You can also set CORS permissions on the bucket itself, and my bucket has those set up

Answer (score 2):

With the help of the Google Cloud Support team, I figured out the ContentType was incorrect. I changed the options to:

```
contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
```

and it worked!